# Google sample BluetoothAdvertisements not detecting advertisements

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a BLE wearable (running on Tizen 3.0) sending out BLE advertisements. The advertisements get immediately detected by the Nordic nRF Android App.

However, the [BluetoothAdvertisements Google sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothAdvertisements) detects none.

In `ScannerFragment.buildScanFilters()`, I did set the filters to see all BLE devices around.

The platform is Android 8.1.0 on Google Pixel.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[image]]
[image]]

Comment: Apps also need location permission for BLE scans now.does this sample has location permission at Runtime?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I uninstalled the app, added both `...ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `...ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and then ran again with no effect.

Comment: Issue resolved: my mistake was failing to request the location permissions during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Apps also need location permission for BLE scans now.does this sample has location permission at Runtime?

PS.
posted this as  answer after @user2551017 said it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Solution: request the location permissions during runtime